# Chrome.windows.onCreated in background script wont recognize browsers first opening

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I need to call some method on opening browser from background page in my chrome extension. It works for me on my pc and chrome, but on some other pc's and same version chrome not working. Working only if second browser is opened. Somehow that chrome's api dont see first browser is opened.
Chrome version latest (75.0.3770.90)

```
chrome.windows.onCreated.addListener((window) => {
    this.doSomething(window);
});

function doSomething(window) {
    console.log('Window with id: ', window.id, 'opened'); 
}
```

I expect to console log every windowId which is opened, but i get only from second opened window.

Comment: Chrome starts the background script after the main startup sequence has completed which is why your onCreated isn't fired.

Comment: @wOxxOm is there some workaround for this behavior? This working if i turn on devtools for background page.

Comment: There's no real workaround. You can make your extension always run in the background even when no browser windows are opened by adding "background" in "permissions" and enabling "Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed" in browser settings.

Comment: Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed is on, and if i put interval on 1sec in background script to console.log('something') and close google chrome, it will writing 'something' every second. Do you have some other solution for this? Thanks for this tips

Comment: I don't see any real solutions. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Adding "background" in "permissions" solved this issue. Thanks @wOxxOm
I am trying to achieve to doSomethingOnOpeningBrowser(), and to doSomethingOtherOnClosingBrowser(). Some kind of call methods automatically on this events.

Comment: Might wanna use [chrome.runtime.onStartup](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onStartup).